# How to get task result in dask scheduler plugin

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I want to forward the result of a task with a scheduler plugin in dask. I have a class that is registered and when I log in the transition function it shows:

> transition: key=, start=processing, finish=memory, *args=(), **kwargs={'worker': 'tcp://127.0.0.1:51514', 'status': 'OK', 'nbytes': 95196, 'thread': 123145458712576, 'type': b'\x80\x04\x95\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x05tuple\x94\x93\x94.', 'startstops': (('compute', 1554303315.1791308, 1554303315.1879702),)}

How can I get the actual result of the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the scheduler does not store the results of tasks, at most it knows the type and size of the outputs that are being stored on workers. It would be an anti-pattern to move data to the scheduler, please don't be tempted to do that. If you wanted more information about outputs, it would make sense to calculate those on the workers containing the data.

Comment: Thanks, I realised I should be more general with what I'm trying to accomplish. I just made a different question for this if you have thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513623/how-can-i-get-result-of-dask-compute-on-a-different-machine-than-the-one-that-su