# How can I get result of Dask compute on a different machine than the one that submitted it?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I am using Dask behind a Django server and the basic setup I have is summarised here: https://github.com/MoonVision/django-dask-demo/ where the Dask client can be found here: https://github.com/MoonVision/django-dask-demo/blob/master/demo/daskmanager/daskmanager.py

I want to be able to separate the saving of a task from the server that submitted it for robustness and scalability. I also would like more detailed information as to the processing status of the task, right now the future status is always pending even if the task is processing. Having a rough estimate of percent complete would also be great.

Right now, if the web server were to die, the client would get deleted and the task would stop as no client is still holding the future. I can get around this by using [fire_and_forget](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#fire-and-forget) but I then have no way to save the task status and result when it completes.

Ways I see to track the status and save the result after a fire_and_forget:

1. I could have a scheduler plugin that sends all transfers to AMPQ server (RabbitMQ). I like the robustness and being able to subscribe to certain messages that are output by the scheduler and knowing every message will be processed. I'm not sure how I could get the result it self with this method. I could manually adding a node to the end of every graph to save the result but would rather have it be behind the scenes.
2. [get_task_stream](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.get_task_stream) on separate server or use it in some way. With this, it seems I could miss some messages if the server were to go down so seems like a worse option 1.
3. Other option?

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Edit: Just tested and it seems when the client that submitted a task shuts down, all futures it created are moved from processing to forgotten, even if calling fire_and_forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at Dask's coordination primitivies like Queues and Pub/Sub.  My guess is that putting your futures into a queue would solve your problem.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#coordination-primitives

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Put futures into a queue so that client can restart and have separate process checking the queue for finished futures. Thanks!

Comment: Can Futures be stored in something like a redis store?

Comment: The key of a future could be, and any process could recreate a future from that key.  This is just a pointer though.  You'll still need Dask to hold onto a future somewhere in order to make sure that that data gets kept around.